# The z-index fixed div at the top does not seem to work

Tags: html, css

I want this div at the top of my page which will stay fixed through out my whole page and will overlap any crossing element. Just like the top blue search bar that facebook has.
When ever i scroll down, the table comes above the div but i want the opposite. Well here is the code. And when I use the z-index, the images on my div becomes yellowish.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

#fixedDiv{                  
position:fixed;
z-index:1;
top:0px;
left:0px;
border:3px groove blue;
height:200px;
width:1360px;
background-color:yellow;
opacity:.4;
margin-right:10px;
}

p.fixPara{  
z-index:1;              
position:fixed;
letter-spacing:20px;
font-size:50px;
font-weight:bold;
color:purple;
top:20px;
left:7em;
}

table{
background-color:white;
border:3px outset navy;
width:700px;
height:500px;
margin-top:1000px;
margin-left:300px;
}

tr>td{
padding:15px;
font-size:20px;
text-align:center

</style>
</head>

<body>

<div id="fixedDiv"><p class="fixPara">This is Fixed!!</p></div>

<img src="grass.jpg" style="position:fixed;right:3px;top:3px;" height=100px width=150px>
<img src="black.jpg" style="position:fixed;top:3px;left:3px;" height=100px; width=150px>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="3"><h2>VISIT THE SUITABLE LINK</h2></th>
    </tr>
        <td>Google</td>
        <td>Youtube</td>
        <td>Facebook</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Kickass to</td>
        <td>JAVA</td>
        <td>Apple</td>
    </tr>

</table>    

</body>
</html>
```

Adding [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/C2wGk/12/)

Comment: last css style is not closed for your info

Comment: FYI: `opacity:.4` is creating problem! see [this](http://jsfiddle.net/dTY47/)

Comment: i closed the style. But still it does not seem to work @Shadow

Comment: that is not your issue...I just menat to inform u

Comment: @DhavalMarthak thank you now it works. But what if i want that exact color to work, and you know to overlap other elements?

Comment: @raiyan106 Use `#ffff99` instead, if you want this kind of yellow, without opacity.

Answer (score 0):

first of all close last css style,
you need remove opacity
 and add `img` tag `z-index:5;`

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/C2wGk/14/)

```
#fixedDiv {
    background-color: yellow;
    border: 3px groove blue;
    height: 200px;
    left: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    opacity: 0.4;/*remove*/
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 1360px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go;

html:

```
<div id="fixedDiv"><div class="opacity"><p class="fixPara">This is Fixed!!</p></div></div>
```

css:

```
.opacity {
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.4) !important; 
width: 100%;
height: 200px;
```

}

```
#fixedDiv {background-color:#fff !Important}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/C2wGk/12/